How to Remove Elements from ListView.builder and Refresh the List in Flutter
I’m working on a Flutter project where I need to remove elements from a ListView.builder and refresh the list to reflect these changes. However, I’m encountering issues where the list does not update correctly after removing an item. Here is a simplified version of my code:
class List extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListState createState() => _ListState();
}

class _ListState extends State<List> {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> taskData = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'List 1', 'status': 'Pending'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'List 2', 'status': 'Completed'},
    // More tasks...
  ];

  void removeList(int taskId) {
    setState(() {
      taskData.removeWhere((element) => element['id'] == taskId);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Task List')),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: taskData.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(taskData[index]['name']),
            trailing: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
              onPressed: () => removeList(taskData[index]['id']),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

When I remove a task using the delete button, the ListView.builder does not refresh automatically to reflect the changes. I have to navigate away from the screen and come back to see the updated list.
Using setState to update the list.
Ensuring the list is updated correctly within the setState method.
Using unique keys for list items.
How can I ensure that the ListView.builder refreshes automatically when an item is removed? Are there any best practices or alternative approaches to achieve this in Flutter?

Current version of code will never work, and it is not eve compilable, unfortunately. taskData should be ListData and  removeList should be removeTask, am I right?

class List extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListState createState() => _ListState();
}

class _ListState extends State<List> {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> taskData = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'List 1', 'status': 'Pending'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'List 2', 'status': 'Completed'},
    // More tasks...
  ];

  void removeTask(int taskId) {
    setState(() {
      taskData.removeWhere((element) => element['id'] == taskId);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Task List')),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: taskData.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(taskData[index]['name']),
            trailing: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
              onPressed: () => removeTask(taskData[index]['id']),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


What is the change in this code?

I Updated the removeTask method to remove the task from taskData using removeWhere.
Then I Called removeTask with the correct task ID when the delete button is pressed.

My answer will be for last part of the question, about best practices and alternative approaches.
As per documentation, it is not recommended to perform any computation in setState() method, because it could be a reason for junky UI.
removeWhere is "computation" in this context, cause it has O(N) Tim-complexity and can have major performance impact. So, maybe it is worth it to sacrifice a little memory space and do something like this, in functional way:
  void removeTask(int taskId) {
    final newList =
        ListData.where((element) => element['id'] != taskId).toList();
    setState(() {
      ListData = newList;
    });
  }

In that case, there is no computation inside setState
But in my opinion, it is better to use ValueNotifier in this case:
class _HomePageState extends State<_HomePage> {
  // Create ValueNotifier instead simple list
  ValueNotifier<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> ListData = ValueNotifier([
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'List 1', 'status': 'Pending'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'List 2', 'status': 'Completed'},
    // More tasks...
  ]);

  // Modify this method so there is no more setState, only updating value
  // of ValueNotifier
  void removeTask(int taskId) {
    ListData.value =
        ListData.value.where((element) => element['id'] != taskId).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // Wraps ListView.builder in ValueListenableBuilder, which will react
      // on ListData changes.
      // It may not have much sense here, but in comples widgets,
      // you can use this widget down in nested tree of widgets, and changes in it
      // will not affect outer tree
      body: ValueListenableBuilder(
        valueListenable: ListData,
        builder: (context, value, child) => ListView.builder(
          itemCount: value.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(value[index]['name']),
              trailing: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                onPressed: () => removeTask(value[index]['id']),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

